# How to use imported values in React PropTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm creating `PropTypes` for a functional component and I want to use `PropTypes.oneOf` with an object imported from another file:

```
import { MODES } from '../../../Users';
(...)
ManageUserForm.propTypes = {
    mode: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(MODES)),
}
```

In `Users.js`, *MODES* looks like this:

```
export const MODES = {
    add: 'add', edit: 'edit', changePassword: 'changePassword',
    block: 'block', unblock: 'unblock', delete: 'delete'
};
```

But I get an error stating that *MODES* is `undefined`. For now, I solved it by just hardcoding the values, but that's inelegant and I want to improve it. What can I do?

EDIT: I recreated the problem in a sandbox:
[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/import-problem-in-proptypes-531s0?file=/src/ManageUserForm.js)

Comment: Can you recreate in a sandbox?

Comment: @DennisVash, I did- check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **circular dependency**.

1. First the code imports `Users.js` from `App.js`.
2. Then `Users.js` imports `UserCreator.js`.
3. Then `UserCreator.js` imports `ManageUserForm.js`.
4. Then `ManageUserForm.js` imports `Users.js` again

All this even before `MODES` variable is being defined.
You should not import `Users.js` in `ManageUserForm.js` since `Users.js` itself depends on `ManageUserForm.js` through `UserCreator.js`.

You can move `MODES` definition to `ManageUserForm.js` and import it in `Users.js` or better move it to a separate file completely.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed- that's exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

This would work but I will recommend to keep it in the same file because it was not imported when it defines the proptypes.

```
ManageUserForm.propTypes = {
  mode: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(require('../../../Users'))),
}
```

**Here is a codeSandbox example**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-y1br4?file=/index.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see where and how MODES is used in your examples- especially in the sandbox example

Comment: I forgot to save my example, please check the link again

Comment: thank you, now I know, what you meant and I applied it and it works. However, surprisingly, since I extracted the constant to a separate file I don't need to use anything like `require`, I just use it as I wanted at the beginning: `mode: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(MODES))`